# ncftpput don't create parent directory

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ncftp

I am trying to upload multiple directories recursively to an FTP server, (and FTP is the only way).

Say I have the following environment:

Remote:

```
/
/remote-files/
/readme.txt
```

Local:

```
/my-website.com/
/my-website.com/dir1/file1.txt
/my-website.com/dir2/file2.txt
```

If I issue the following command:

```
ncftpput -R -v -u "root" -p "root" 149.xxx.xxx.xxx / /my-website.com
```

The result would be:

```
/
/remote-files/
/readme.txt
/my-website.com/
/my-website.com/dir1/file1.txt
/my-website.com/dir2/file2.txt
```

What I desired:

```
/
/remote-files/
/readme.txt
/dir1/file1.txt
/dir2/file2.txt
```

I tried:

```
ncftpput -R -v -u "root" -p "root" 149.xxx.xxx.xxx / /my-website.com/
```

but it makes no difference.

How to do it?

Or should I use other program?

Thank you.